# Incorrect syntax code for pass command line arguments to a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
namespace :mails do
  desc "Send emails"
  task :send_emails => :environment do
    User.not_deleted.find_each do |user|
      Notifier.confirm_about_paid_access(user.id).deliver
    end
  end

  desc "Free subscription for users registered in 2011"
  task :free_subscription_for => :environment, :year do |t, args|
    year = args[:year]
    users = User::registered_in(year)
  end
end
```

displaying error:  **lib/tasks/mails.rake:10: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting =>
 task :free_subscription_for => :environment, :year do |t, args|**

What is incorrect in syntax code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
namespace :mails do
  desc "Send emails"
  task :send_emails => :environment do
    User.not_deleted.find_each do |user|
      Notifier.confirm_about_paid_access(user.id).deliver
    end
  end

  desc "Free subscription for users registered in 2011"
  task :free_subscription_for, [:year] => :environment do |t, args|
    year = args[:year]
    users = User::registered_in(year)
  end
end
```

Notice the syntax for `:free_subscription_for` task.

And while executing the task the syntax would be `rake mails:free_subscription_for["2016"]`

Hope this helps!